# 46: regex error 17 for `(dryad-bibo/v)[0-9].[0-9]', (match failed)

Tags: c++, macos, ubuntu, mime-types, libmagic

I'm trying to determine the mime-type for several types of files using libmagic and the following bit of code:

```
auto handle = ::magic_open(MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);
::magic_load(handle, NULL);

// Both of these fail with the same error
// file_path being a const char* with the path to the file.
auto type2 = ::magic_file(handle, file_path);

// svg_content being an std::vector<char> with the contents of the file.
//auto type2 = ::magic_buffer(handle, svg_content.data(), svg_content.size()); 

if(!type2)
{
   std::cout << magic_error(handle) << std::endl;
}
    
::magic_close(handle);
```

But for any file or buffer I try I receive regex error, either being or similar to:

> 46: regex error 17 for `(dryad-bibo/v)[0-9].[0-9]', (match failed)

For example with this .svg file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="flag-icon-css-no" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
  <path fill="#ed2939" d="M0 0h640v480H0z"/>
  <path fill="#fff" d="M180 0h120v480H180z"/>
  <path fill="#fff" d="M0 180h640v120H0z"/>
  <path fill="#002664" d="M210 0h60v480h-60z"/>
  <path fill="#002664" d="M0 210h640v60H0z"/>
</svg>
```

What I've tried so far:

- libmagic 5.35
- libmagic 5.39
- libmagic 5.40
- libmagic from opensource.apple
- setting LC_TYPE and LANG to "C"

I'm linking against a version of libmagic that was built locally, could there be anything I have missed while building? Are any of the calls incorrect or is there something I'm missing?

I get similar errors when trying to run the related file binary that was compiled locally. Whereas when I use the file command that is available by default I do get image/svg+xml as output.

**Edit**

To build libmagic (for macOS and Ubuntu), I followed these steps:

- Downloaded relevant release from [Github](https://github.com/file/file/releases)
- autoreconf --install
- ./configure
- make
- make install

**Update**

It looks like the regex at the bottom of this file is causing issues (at least for the svg):

> https://github.com/file/file/blob/b56b58d499dbe58f2bed28e6b3c297fe7add992e/magic/Magdir/dataone

**Update 2**

Something strange going on; On the system where I've got it working, `magic_version()` reports *540*, as expected. But on the systems where it fails with this error, `magic_version()` reports *538*.

This makes little sense to me as I can't find that version on the system itself anywhere and when I run `./file --version` in the build library, it reports `file-5.40`.

Comment: Why don't you use a parser instead?

Comment: I want to detect the mime-type of several different files and content without a filename, not just svg - that's an example. As far as I know libmagic is the best candidate for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very dissatisfying answer, but it was linking against [GoogleTest](https://github.com/google/googletest) causing this error somehow, not even running any tests, just linking against it.

I switched to using [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) instead and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.:

Clone the repo

```
git clone git@github.com:file/file.git
cd file/
```

Try this in fresh clone of the repo:

```
autoreconf -f -i
./configure --disable-silent-rules
make -j4
make -C tests check
```

And see whether there are any errors reported. After installation with `make install`, grab some valid xml file named as "test.xml" and put it to some folder together with this `main.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <magic.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *actual_file = "test.xml";
    const char *magic_full;
    magic_t magic_cookie;

    /* MAGIC_MIME tells magic to return a mime of the file,
       but you can specify different things */
    magic_cookie = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME);

    if (magic_cookie == NULL) {
        printf("unable to initialize magic library\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Loading default magic database\n");

    if (magic_load(magic_cookie, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("cannot load magic database - %s\n", magic_error(magic_cookie));
        magic_close(magic_cookie);
        return 1;
    }

    magic_full = magic_file(magic_cookie, actual_file);
    printf("%s\n", magic_full);
    magic_close(magic_cookie);
    return 0;
}
```

(Courtesy to [vivithemage](https://gist.github.com/vivithemage/9489378).)

Compile and try:

```
$ gcc main.c -lmagic
$ ./a.out 
Loading default magic database
text/xml; charset=us-ascii
```

If it does not work on your system, report bug on [project's bugtracker](https://bugs.astron.com/my_view_page.php) with specification of your OS and architecture. You can try to hotfix your problem by removing offending record from the file you have found in your update.

Comment: It fails on setup with `make: *** No rule to make target `distclean'.`

Comment: @Thizzer, that is my mistake, I have removed the step, it does the same here on my Ubuntu. Sorry for that. Fixed in the answer. I have copied directly from documentation, I will also fix the stuff upstream...

Comment: Reported: https://bugs.astron.com/view.php?id=290

Comment: Something strange going on; On the system where I've got it working, magic_version() reports 540, as expected. But on the systems where it fails with this error, magic_version() reports 538. This makes little sense to me as I can't find that version on the system itself anywhere.

Comment: Interesting... Search this paths: `echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -` on your system whether you don't have two conflicting installations.

Comment: I fixed the version issue (that was something separate).

Comment: I have to change your compile statement to `gcc main.c -lmagic -lz -lbz2 -llzma` and that caused me to have to install `lzma(-dev)` and `bz2(-dev)`, which makes me wonder how libmagic compiles/compiled itself if it wants those symbols but they're not in place? The compiled script above did work with that though for both and xml and the svg from the example..

Comment: Having to link those extra libraries was of course because I was linking the static version of libmagic, after making it use shared `gcc main.c -lmagic` worked. Still a bit flabbergasted on what is happening, but will get back when I find out more.

Comment: Awarded this answer the bounty as it has helped me the most, but the problem ended up being something related to the linkage of my project against Googletest. Right now, I have no time and desire to figure out the exact cause, and switching to Catch2 solved the issue.